# Why does my object move too far in Unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am really new to Unity so I have some problems...

I want to create a 2D game. I made a button. when pressed the player schould go to x:0 , y:70 .
So I created a canvas. in this canvas a Button: [Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72V3i.png)
In the same canvas I created the player: [Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHTRg.png)

I made this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

   public void moveUp()
   {
       transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1 ,0);
   }
}
```

but the player doest go to 0,1. It goes to 0,60 ...

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Check if you script is attached to child object of player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform.position` this is the global position. If you are checking the position shown in the inspector, that is the `localPosition`, which is relative to the parent, and is affected by the transform of all of its ancestors in the hierarchy.

If you want to your transformation changes to be the same as what the inspector shows you need to modify `transform.localPosition`.

Comment: Thank you! It helped. You are a hero